# Python urllib basic script for youtube

Tags: python, youtube, urllib

I am trying to download a video from Youtube, and have tried the following:

```
url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4l3pBovB_c"
urllib.urlretrieve(url,"test.mp4")
```

It creates the file test.mp4, but got the following error:

> Windows media player cannot play the file. The Player might not
>   support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to
>   compress the file.

I would like to try to understand how to accomplish this myself, I have seen modules like youtube-dl.py, but again would like to get the code working in it's simplest form so I can understand the script as I build it.

Comment: You are downloading a HTML site like that. Of course that is not playable in your media player. The actual video file is hidden by YouTube.

Comment: @user1947457: As this question is old, do you still require an answer to this question?

Comment: Hi Awainb; would still like an answer, or to be pointed in the right direction. Mainly I would like to use python to save the audio from youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube videos are not stored on `youtube.com` domain, so the video which you are trying to download does not exist that URL. Downloading a youtube video is a complicated process but you can use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) for it.